# How to store array in local storage angular?

Tags: angular, local-storage, web-storage

I was trying to store data in an array to get it later in other component but it's provoking error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

I used local storage.

```js
onSubmit() {
    let email = this.AuthForm.get("email").value;
    let password = this.AuthForm.get("password").value;
    let nomcomplet = "";
    let occupation = "";
    let niveau = 0;
    let newUser = new User(email, password, nomcomplet, occupation, niveau);
    console.log(newUser);
    let val: any = [];
    val = this.storage.get(this.key);
    val.push(newUser.email);
    this.storage.set(this.key, JSON.stringify(val));
}
```

I expected to find all the stored values in the local storage but the actual is error and only the last value get stored before

screen capture

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ber1J.png)

Comment: what does the console.log(newuser) return?

Comment: When you get array from localStorage use `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem())`.

Comment: hi thank u but sorry that did nit work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've stored your data as a string, so when you retrieve it you should parse it back to be an object.

*set storage*

```
this.storage.set(this.key, JSON.stringify(val));
```

*retrieve from stroage*

```
const storageVal = this.storage.get(this.key)
const val = JSON.parse(storageVal)
```

You may also want to add a method to handle cases where the storage object does not exist (returns a `null` value)

```
const storageVal = this.storage.get(this.key)
const val = storageVal ? JSON.parse(storageVal) : []
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok let´s Try this

```
     let email = this.AuthForm.get("email").value;
     let password = this.AuthForm.get("password").value;
     let nomcomplet = "";
     let occupation = "";
     let niveau = 0;
     let newUser = new User(email, password, nomcomplet, occupation, niveau);
     console.log(newUser);
     let array: any = [];

     if (localStorage.getItem(keyToFindOrSave)) {
      //exist data on storage
      //so grab the storage
       array = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(this.key)); //we overwrite the same arry with the data from LocalStorage

    }

      console.log(array); //Watching if have some old data!
      array.push(newUser) //So we push the newUser , if exist something on localStorage the if before actually have the data
      console.log(array); //Watching with new data and old data
      localStorage.set(keyToFindOrSave, JSON.stringify(array)); //and save the data
```

Remember that `keyToFindOrSave` allways need to be the same (y)

And when you need the data on another component just grab with

```
let dataFromStorage : any;
if (localStorage.getItem(keyToFindOrSave)) { //always ask if exist the localStorage =D
 dataFromStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getgetItem(keyToFindOrSave));
}
```

[Some Screenshot LocalStorage Data](http://prntscr.com/ox0gjl)

Comment: I edited the post and shared a link of screen capture in the browser storage,

Comment: the values are non ordered , it's like a guarbage , accessing to them will be so hard

Comment: what i want to see is every object stored with it's own index,

Comment: 1/            second value

Comment: let array: any = [];
    if (localStorage.getItem('session')) {
      const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(this.key)); //we need Parse the data coming from storage like string
      array.push(data);
       //we save the previous data on localStorage
    }

    console.log(array); //Watching if have some old data!
    array.push(newUser) //So we push the newUser , if exist something on localStorage the if before actually have the data
    console.log(array); 
    localStorage.setItem(this.key, JSON.stringify(array));

Comment: modify this  `if (localStorage.getItem(keyToFindOrSave)) {
      //exist data on storage
      //so grab the storage
       array = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(this.key)); // this was my bad, always pushing a new array sorry =D

    }`